# Having Top team of every season (only one)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want only top teams whose wins are most in each season.

[image]

**I want my Result set as Season: 1900 team_name: 'a' wins:4 and like this for 1901 it will be Team: 'b' wins:5**

If there are two teams wins same then my query should pick the first one alphabetically like in my case it will pick Team: 'a' for season 1900

Source Query

```
create table #teams( season varchar(100), team_name varchar(100),win int);

insert #teams (season , team_name ,win)
select '1900','a' , 4;

insert #teams (season , team_name ,win)
select '1900','b' , 4;

insert #teams (season , team_name ,win)
select '1900','c' , 2;

insert #teams (season , team_name ,win)
select '1901','a' , 3;

insert #teams (season , team_name ,win)
select '1901','b' , 5;

insert #teams (season , team_name ,win)
select '1901','c' , 5;

select * from #teams;

select season ,team_name , max(win) as wins
from #teams
group by season, team_name
order by season
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work..

I am ordering by the number of win desc, and also by the team_name asc which should cater to the condition of choosing the alphabetically superior team to be in the final list.

```
select * from (
select season 
      ,team_name 
      ,win
      ,row_number() over(partition by season order by win desc,team_name asc) as rnk
  from teams
    )x
where x.rnk=1 


+--------+-----------+-----+-----+
| season | team_name | win | rnk |
+--------+-----------+-----+-----+
|   1900 | a         |   4 |   1 |
|   1901 | b         |   5 |   1 |
+--------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

full db fiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abd425477e893e3dd869467daab4f216

Answer (score 0):

A Couple methods:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT season,
           team_name,
           wins,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Season ORDER BY wins DESC, team_name ASC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT season,
       team_name,
       win
FROM CTE
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = 1;

SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       season,
       team_name,
       wins
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Season ORDER BY wins DESC);
```

`DENSE_RANK` will return all teams with the most wins, where as `ROW_NUMBER` will return a the first team alphabetically (due to the additional value in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: the OP was asking to choose the alphabetically closer one in case of ties